# AND where queries in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get my head around this. I have a query as such:

```
                $this->db->select("*");
                $where = array(
                  'category_id' => $category_id,
                  'active'   => 1
                );
                $this->db->where($where);
                $blogs_query= $this->db->get('blog');
```

I was hoping that would retrieve all the active blogs which matches the category_id I supplied. However it is retrieving all the blogs that matches the category and all the blogs that are active and do not necessarily matches the category.

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db-query("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE category_id = ? AND active = ?",array($category_id,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple query :

```
           $where = array(
              'category_id' => $category_id,
              'active'   => '1'
            );
            $blogs_query= $this->db->select("*")
                                   ->from('blog')
                                   ->where($where)
                                   ->get();
```

Here the main change is **'active'=> '1'** instead of **'active' => 1** 
It should work, I haven't tested it.